# Setting security permissions on language versions in Sitecore

Tags: security, sitecore, versions

got a bit of a query.

I am working on a multi-language site, currently only 5 languages: English, French, German, Italian and English US.

I am setting up roles for each language which will mean that the French user can only edit the French version of an item, but they can read the other language versions of that item. This has been set up using the language read and language write access rights and is working fine.

The problem is that when a French user browses to an item that only has a version in English (no version in french, no version in German, no version in italian), the French user is then able to create a German version of that item - despite not having the language write right on German. So the French user is  able to create a German version of the item, but cannot enter any data (which is correct because they havent got language write on that language).

The question is... how do I stop a French user from being able to create a version in German?

Answer (score 0):

Did you deny the French role "create" rights on the other languages?
If that is not gonna work, you can create a custom event which is handled when the user tries to create a new version of an item:

```
<event name="item:versionAdding"/>
```

In this event you can check the users language rights and deny them creating a version in another language.

Comment: As I've said above, I set the create rights on the other languages. The problem is with the version. The French user can create a german version of an item, but cannot then edit that german version once they've created it. This means that the rights are correct with regards to editing/writing, but for some reason Sitecore allows version create. Dont know why

Comment: I was talking about the "Create" right on the German language. (You didn't mention it, only read/write rights which are different rights) Is the "create" right explicitly denied for the French role in the German langauge? You can use the access-viewer to check the actual rights per role/user.

Comment: Yes, the "Create" right on the German Language item is denied for French user role... but it still allows the creation of a german version by a french user